# 2 different sortables in same list

Tags: jquery, css

I have made this example code to illustrate my problem:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

        <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
                function InitSortable() {
                    $('.sortable').sortable();
                }    
        </script>

        <style>           
            .sortable { width: 200px; padding: 10px; border: solid 1px black; } 
            .sortable div { float: left; width: 80px; border: solid 1px black; margin-left: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; background-color: White; padding: 2px; } 
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body onload="InitSortable()">            
        <div class="sortable">   
            <div>Process A</div>
            <div>Process B</div>
            <div>Process C</div>

            <div>File A</div>
            <div>File B</div>
            <div>File C</div>   
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to sort Process A, ProcessB and Process C without messing up the sort on File A, File B and File C. And I want it to work in opposite way if I try to sort any of the File elements.

I have tried to put those 2 lists in their own div, but that breakes the design, all elements should float to left.

I have also played around with the items option in jquery, but I only manage to get one of the lists work.

Comment: You could distinguish the "Processes" as you call them by giving them some class. Then you could edit their order without touching the "Files". Besides the correct way to do it is as you say put those things in different divs and change your styles so that they don't break..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to initialize/destroy the sortable each time you want to do some sorting, and each time you will initialize it you will do for the type of elements you want..

So, add a different class to each type of elements you want grouped..

```
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="process">Process A</div>
        <div class="process">Process B</div>
        <div class="process">Process C</div>

        <div class="file">File A</div>
        <div class="file">File B</div>
        <div class="file">File C</div>   
    </div>
```

And in your script use

```
function InitSortable() {
    $('.sortable > div').mousedown(function(){
        $(this).closest('.sortable').sortable({
            items:'.'+this.className,
            stop:function(){
                $(this).sortable('destroy');
            }
        });
    });
}  

$(InitSortable);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/h6aPj/

Answer (score 1):

You say you've tried putting the 2 lists in their own divs but that "breaks the design". I'd be inclined to dispute that - you can create almost any visual appearance you like, whether split into 2 divs or just one.  Try adding a wrapper div to encapsulate your `float: left` styling, then use a different child div for each sortable list. That should sort your problem.